# full text searching for various external formats plone 4.2

Tags: plone

I wanted to enable full text searching in plone 4.2(windows).I ultimately installed Products.OpenXml and ftw.tika addon using buildout and properly adding their packages  in eggs as well as zcml category, after which they both show in portal_transforms tools.
i.e included this in buildout.cfg and ran it.

```
eggs = 
   Products.OpenXml
   ftw.tika
zcml = 
   Products.OpenXml
   ftw.tika
```

But indexing still does not include anything except the title in the searchable field even after using clear and rebuild from plone catalog tool.
Please help me to enable this properly and i am a novice so please explain in detail if possible.

*Or is there another better way(maybe faster,for multiple formats or simply better) to enable full text searching for external formats(doc,pdf,..) in version 4.2.*

Comment: This question is perfectly intelligible within the context of Plone. Reviewers should have just edited to remove the misleading "python" tag rather than voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never installed `ftw.tika` on Windows, but if you manage to setup the service and it's up and running it should work.

To use `ftw.tika`you need to install the `ftw.tika` package on your Plone Site by following the instructions in the [README](https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.tika#installation). This means you need to install the egg and the necessary zcml configuration to point to your local tika app.

```xml
zcml =
    <configure xmlns:tika="http://namespaces.plone.org/tika">
        <tika:config path="${tika-app-download:destination}/${tika-app-download:filename}"
                     port="${tika:server-port}" />
    </configure>
```

Please also make sure you a recent version of JAVA installed, because it tries to run the `tika-app.jar`.

You can check if `ftw.tika` is installed properly by looking into the  portal_transforms tool. There should be a `tika_to_plain_text` transform (http://plone/portal_transforms/tika_to_plain_text/manage_main), which should look like this:

[image]

If not, use quickinstaller, or portal_setup to install ftw.tika.

Also the server should run fine on windows, it's also Java. I guess you cannot use the examples from the package instructions, since they're made for Unix machines.

Comment: Yes my portal_tranforms contains tika_to_plain_text and i had installed it using the buildout by adding necessary configurations in both egg include and zcml category and it was installed fine,at least with no errors.But STILL my index does not include the full text as needed after clear and rebuild.Please suggest corrections or some better method for fulltext searching.

Comment: If you upload a file manually (let's say a PDF, or DOCX), there should be a entry in the LOG from ftw.tika. Something like `Converting document with LOCAL tika`. Of course on rebuild, you should see one entry per file. At least in the ftw.tika readme (https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.tika#daemon-buildout-example) there are instruction to setup a daemon.

Comment: You should probably not install both packages at the same time.

Comment: no,i tried it in linux too but still did not work..i created a tika .cfg as given ,extended buildout with tika.cfg and added the zcml part as is.Portal transform shows but does not index anything.

Comment: Sad -.- I assume there is also nothing in log? Can you share your buildout? on pastebin or similar?

Comment: actually just tried the non daemon buildout example in windows...it works!! but the daemon buildout one does not...now In linux i am trying it in a zeocluster but please tell me where to write the zcml-additional part..thanks and cant vote up less reputation..sorry

Comment: Cool it works on windows, that's a success :-) for the daemon part you can extend your buildout.cfg on linux with `extends = https://raw.githubusercontent.com/4teamwork/ftw.tika/master/tika.cfg`. Then you need to modify then `instance` part (or the part which uses the plone.recipe.zope2instance recipe) with `zcml-additional += ${tika:zcml}`.

Comment: Then you can start the daemon using `.bin/tika-server`, or if supervisor is there you can start it with supervisor.